# How would I approach generating a vector of n random company names to use as test data in R?

Tags: r

```
install.packages("wakefield") 
install.packages("randomNames")
install.packages('password')
install.packages('OpenRepGrid')
library(password)
library(wakefield)
library(randomNames)

locations <- c('Northwest', 'Midwest', 'Northeast', 'South', 'Southwest', 'Southeast', 
'International') # Vec of locations used
n <- 100 # number of data points generated
locPrefs <- numeric(n) # empty vec
randNum <- function(){ # Generate random num func
  randNum <- floor(runif(1,1,7))
  return(randNum)
}
for(i in 1:100){
  locPrefs[i] <- locations[randNum()]
}


studentData <- data.frame('first names'=randomNames(n, which.names = 'first'),'last 
names'=randomNames(n, which.names = 'last'),'username'=seq(1, 
n),'password'=password(8,numbers=TRUE),'gpa'=gpa(n, mean = 85.356, sd = 3.2, name = 
"GPA"),'visa'=sample(c("N","Y"), size = n, replace = TRUE, prob = c(.78, .22)), 'loc 
pref'=locPrefs) # data frame of data generated for students
```

I am generating data to test a matching algorithm for matching students and employers and need to generate a vector of length n of some random company names. Some help generating these company names would be great.

Answer (score 2):

With some real world data also using `sample`:

```
sp500 <- read.csv("http://www.princeton.edu/~otorres/sandp500.csv")
sample(sp500$Name, 100)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
names = c("company 1", "company 2", "company 3")
sample(names, n)
```

Where n is the size of the vector you want. You can set `replace=TRUE` to have a replaced draw.